# Why I cannot update an array in cluster mode but could in pseudo-distributed

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark

I wrote a spark program in scala, of which the main codes are:

```
val centers:Array[(Vector,Double)] = initCenters(k)
val sumsMap:Map(int,(vector,int))= data.mapPartitions{
    ***
}.reduceByKey(***).collectAsMap()
sumsMap.foreach{case(index,(sum,count))=>
   sum/=count
   centers(index)=(sum,sum.norm2())
}
```

the origin codes are:

```
 val centers = initCenters.getOrElse(initCenter(data))

val br_centers = data.sparkContext.broadcast(centers)
val trainData = data.map(e => (e._2, e._2.norm2)).cache()
val squareStopBound = stopBound * stopBound
var isConvergence = false
var i = 0
val costs = data.sparkContext.doubleAccumulator

while (!isConvergence && i < maxIters) {
  costs.reset()
  val res = trainData.mapPartitions { iter =>
    val counts = new Array[Int](k)
    util.Arrays.fill(counts, 0)
    val partSum = (0 until k).map(e => new DenseVector(br_centers.value(0)._1.size))

    iter.foreach { e =>
      val (index, cost) = KMeans.findNearest(e, br_centers.value)
      costs.add(cost)
      counts(index) += 1
      partSum(index) += e._1
    }
    counts.indices.filter(j => counts(j) > 0).map(j => (j -> (partSum(j), counts(j)))).iterator
  }.reduceByKey { case ((s1, c1), (s2, c2)) =>
    (s1 += s2, c1 + c2)
  }.collectAsMap()
  br_centers.unpersist(false)


  println(s"cost at iter: $i is: ${costs.value}")
  isConvergence = true
  res.foreach { case (index, (sum, count)) =>
    sum /= count
    val sumNorm2 = sum.norm2()
    val squareDist = math.pow(centers(index)._2, 2.0) + math.pow(sumNorm2, 2.0) - 2 * (centers(index)._1 * sum)
    if (squareDist >= squareStopBound) {
      isConvergence = false
    }
    centers.update(index,(sum, sumNorm2))
  }
  i += 1
}
```

when these run in a pseudo-distributed mode in IDEA, I get the centers updated, while when I get these run on a spark cluster, I do not get the centers updated.

Comment: There's nowhere near enough information in your question to answer it.  Please provide the lambdas.

Comment: @TimP  thank you very much for you attention, it's a K-Means Algorithm, and I can not get a correct result from these code.

Comment: What is the error you get?  Your code block starting with `res.foreach` is never executed?

Comment: I doubt that the updating of the array centers did not succeed. For the code have run 2 epochs of the outer iteration, I think the `res.foreach` was  executed.

Comment: On the spark cluster,  I do not know why these codes only run 2 outer epochs. it is highly appreciate if you can help me deal with this bug. [the project linkage](https://github.com/Ru-Xiang/LIBBLE-Spark)

Comment: ok, I think I see the problem.  I'll post in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LostInOverflow's answer is correct, but not especially descriptive as to what's going on.

Here are some important properties of your code:

1. declare an array `centers`
2. broadcast this array as `br_centers`
3. update `centers` iteratively

So **how is this going wrong?**  Well, broadcasts are static.  If I write:

```
val a = Array(1,2,3)
val aBc = sc.broadcast(a)
a(0) = 67
```

and access `aBc.value(0)`, I'm going to get different results depending on whether this code was run on the driver JVM or not.  Broadcasting takes an object, torrents it across the network to each node, and creates a new reference in each JVM.  This reference exists as it did when the base object was broadcasted, and it is NOT updated in real time as you mutate the base object.

**What's the solution?**  I think moving the broadcast inside the `while` loop so that you broadcast the updated `centers` should work:

```
while (!isConvergence && i < maxIters) {
  val br_centers = data.sparkContext.broadcast(centers)
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check [Understanding closures](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#understanding-closures-a-nameclosureslinka) section in the programming guide.

Spark is a distributed system and behavior of the code you've shown is simply undefined. It works in local mode only by accident because it executes everything in a single JVM.

Comment: It doesn't change the answer. You modify variable capture by the closure and it is not supported.

Comment: are you getting Serialization exception in cluster mode? or what exception you are getting ?

Comment: @PrudviSagar no exception get

Comment: @LostInOverflow  Please note that the sumsMap is a Map on master, not a RDD.